# How to merge matplotlib.collections?

Tags: matplotlib

How to merge or concatenate matplotlib.collections ?

Image you have 2 different matplotlib.collections produced by two different calls to scatter and then want to use contains on the both collections to listen to a mouse event.
Is is possible ?

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(8,6))
sc1 = ax.scatter([12,23,34],[2,6,4])
sc2 = ax.scatter([19,3,14],[3,8,1])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem with merging multiple `PolyCollection`s. I ended up writing this function to merge multiple collections:

```
import itertools
from matplotlib.collections import PathCollection
import numpy.ma

def merge_poly_collections(collections):
    all_paths = itertools.chain(*(c.get_paths() for c in collections))
    all_arrays = numpy.ma.concatenate([c.get_array() for c in collections])
    result = PathCollection(list(all_paths))
    result.set_array(all_arrays)
    return result
```

I'm relatively sure this should also work with the `PathCollections` returned by `ax.scatter`. In my function I only copied over the paths and the array, but it should be easy to adapt to copy over other attributes of the input collections.